# How to add Custom Buttons in React Datepicker Model

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I want to create a calendar like this.

[image: year sate picker]

The Issue is I don't know how to add `Apply` and `Cancel` button in It. I have tried multiple solutions, But failed to get desired solution.

Through this block of code of I got this.

[image: designed Calendar]

Kindly help me to add Button in `react-datepicker`.

```js
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker'
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date())

<DatePicker
 selected={startDate}
 className='w-[210px] p-3 text-sm font-[Inter-Regular] outline-none text-black-100 '
 onChange={(date) => {
  setStartDate(date as SetStateAction<Date>)
 }}
 showYearPicker
 dateFormat='yyyy'
 yearItemNumber={20}
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the buttons to the datepicker widget as children.

Both are closing the modal using the datepicker widget's api.

We have access to the api through a `ref` we assign to the widget.

The cancel button just set the date to the original<sup>[1]</sup> date.

```
const originalDate = new Date(); // or get it as prop

const [startDate, setStartDate] = React.useState(originalDate);
const calRef = React.useRef();

return (
  <DatePicker
    ref={calRef}
    selected={startDate}
    shouldCloseOnSelect={false}
    onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
    showYearPicker
    dateFormat="yyyy"
    yearItemNumber={20}
  >
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setStartDate(originalDate);
          calRef.current.setOpen(false);
        }}
      >
        Cancel
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          calRef.current.setOpen(false);
        }}
      >
        Apply
      </button>
    </div>
  </DatePicker>
);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-datepicker-footer-buttons?file=App.tsx

---

[1] original - in your example it would be today but if the component receives it as prop, it can be it too